# How to slow down the ouput speed of ffmpeg while streaming to a RTMP server?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, streaming

I'm currently trying to process multipul short videos (each is about 0.5s long) to be stream on a RTMP server. However, the output/fps/speed when sending is too high ([results printed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6120.png)), making the server crashed very often.

Here is the the code and settings that I'm using:

```
import cv2
import ffmpeg
import av
import numpy as np
import os
import subprocess

url = "rtmp://..."
key = "..."
rtmp_url = url + "/" + key

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('traffic.mp4')

# gather video info to ffmpeg
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

# command and params for ffmpeg
command = ['ffmpeg',
           '-y',
           '-f', 'rawvideo',
           '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
           '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
           '-s', "{}x{}".format(width, height),
           '-i', '-',
           '-r', '20',
           '-c:v', 'libx264',
           '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
           '-preset', 'slow',
           '-f', 'flv',
           rtmp_url]

# using subprocess and pipe to fetch frame data
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

received_video_path = 'ReceivedRecording'
while True:
    video_files = [filenames for filenames in sorted(os.listdir(received_video_path), reverse=True)]
    # Loop through the videos and concatenate them
    for filename in video_files[:len(video_files)-3]:
        video = cv2.VideoCapture(os.path.join(received_video_path,filename))

        # Loop through the frames of each video
        while True:
            ret, frame = video.read()
            if not ret:
                # End of video, move to next video
                video.release()
                break
            
            p.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())

        os.remove(os.path.join(received_video_path, filename))
```

The same settings work fine with the webcam, but I can not control the speed and fps of it sending to the server. The stream on the server seems to work fine with a steady 20fps as intended.

Comment: Try adding `-re` argument before the `-i`.

Comment: It seems to work! What does this argument mean, by the way?

Comment: [The -re flag](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#The-reflag)